# Can I set a task to start when any one of its 2 predecessor tasks end?

Tags: ms-project

I have 2 independent tasks running in parallel and need to set a task that begins when either of the first 2 ends.

Can I do this in MS Project, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

Decompose the successor into two separate packages and load fifty percent of the resources in each. When one of the two predecessors finish, it'll trigger the start of one of the two successors.

You will overrun the task that started but will under run the other non started task but the hammock task will be accurate to measure performance.

Comment: Thanks! I saw this answer to a similar question and it would solve the problem, I was wondering if there is a more direct and elegant way of doing this. Maybe some kind of OR operator. I guess not... Thanks anyway.